Mulesoft project build field due to {db::config.db.name)
I'm getting below error while running the mule project,  how do fix it? please can someone help me?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.385 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-01T19:15:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.8.2:process-classes (default-process-classes) on project locations-sys-api: Fail to compile: Referenced component '${secure::db.config.name}' must be one of stereotypes [DB:CONFIG]. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException


This is a statement, not a question.

You haven't shared enough information to understand the issue. Read How to Ask and  provide a minimal reproducible example.

@kunal Awasthi, please check if you declared that db config in the properties file or not.
also please share more details to able to help you like how are you declaring and how did you use it in code

Maybe your db.config.name is not defined in the current property file or that file is not treated with the secure properties configuration.
